# reloadData for UITableView doesn't work in a function with completion

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm trying to call reloadData() function in a calling function using completion handler:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    do{
        var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Actualites")
        let count  = try context.count(for: request)
        if (count == 0) {
            REST().getArticles(limit: 5, limitstart: 0, catid: 6, key: "47347fd312afb0625020028298560d1f", context: context) {  (json) in

                CoreDataHelper().saveArticles(new: true, saveArticles: json, context: context)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }

        actualites = try context.fetch(request) as! [Actualites]
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

When I go into the if count... the uiTableView is not reloaded.

Comment: What is the tableView˚s data source? Did you properly connect it? Why do you use `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` for the second `reload`statement—is anything happening on a background queue? The fetch is being performed after the first `reloadData()` block—intended?

Comment: @TomE the data source is from core data, is well connected, when I go back again in the view a second time the data is showed, when I don't use DispatchQueue.main.async {} it say's UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only

Comment: @TomE The problem is on the first view, when core data is empty, I go in my if count and call the function to get data from REST API, and when I save it in core data I wan't to reload the uiTableView

Comment: @TomE already asks some good question already, just to add to it; I want to add a warning: You are making 3 retain cycles to self. You need to escape self with `[weak self]` in your closures.

Comment: `actualites = try context.fetch(request) as! [Actualites]` you call that before the data has been downloaded. the tableView doesn't know where actualities has come from, so you need to set this value in the completion block or trigger a notification for another function to do it

Comment: @Scriptable my bad, I haven't realize that when I was debugging, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actualites = try context.fetch(request) as! [Actualites]`

`actualities` needs to be updated when you get the response data too. The `UITableView` does not know that this value is filled from a Core data fetch request.

```
do {
        var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Actualites")
        let count  = try context.count(for: request)
        if (count == 0) {
            REST().getArticles(limit: 5, limitstart: 0, catid: 6, key: "47347fd312afb0625020028298560d1f", context: context) {  (json) in

                CoreDataHelper().saveArticles(new: true, saveArticles: json, context: context)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    actualites = try context.fetch(request) as! [Actualites]
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```